# Proof of convergence of $a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n^2 + 1}{3}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and finding its limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

I'm starting a class on Advanced Mathematics I next semester and I found a sheet of the class'es 2012 final exams, so I'm slowly trying to solve the exercises in it or find the general layout. I will be posting a lot of questions with the exercises I find challenging, and I would like to ask for any help or methodologies that will make it easier for me to solve.

I understand the whole ordeal is categorized as **"homework"**, but any assistance would be appreciated, as I'm completely clueless and I would like to be prepared.

The following exercise is $Ex. 2$, graded for $8\%$. It's one of the first ones, and I'd guess easier.

> Prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ that is defined by the recursive type $a_{n+1} = \dfrac{a_n^2 + 1}{3}\;, a_1 = 1$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$ and find its limit.

I've got no insight on this. No idea where to start or how it's supposed to go. What type of proof would this need?

Comment: The first paragraph is something you should put on your profile. The second one ought to be a comment.

Comment: Step 1: Limit exists, because the sequence is decreasing and bounded below. Step 2: The limit obeys the equation x=\frac{x^2+1}{3}$. I don't know how much detail the exam expected for the proof of Step 1.

Comment: Typically in such problems of convergence of sequences defined recursively, it is the case that the sequence is monotonic and bounded (hence convergent). This is probably the way to go. Start by computing the first terms to check what kid of monotinicty if has (if any at all), then try to prove it is monotonic and bounded. As for the limit, recall that $\lim\left( (a_{n+1})_{n\in \mathbb N}\right)=\lim \left((a_{n})_{n\in \mathbb N}\right)$ and take the limit on both sides of the equality that defines the sequence.

Comment: @GitGud I can't make heads or tails about the second part of your comment, taking the two $\lim$s on both sides then continuing the way you say. Guess I'll have to... git gud.

Comment: @DimitrisS. xD $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(a_{n+1}\right)=\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{(a_n)^2+1}3\right)\implies \lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(a_{n+1}\right)=\dfrac {\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}\left(a_{n}\right)^2+1}3.$$ This is just the justification of why solving the equation $x=\dfrac{x^2+1}3$ finds you the limit. Instead of just telling you to solve it, I thought it was better to just take the limits and let you reach the equation yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=\frac{1}{2}(3-\sqrt{5})$.

Step 1: prove by induction that $a_n$ is decreasing and each $a_n$ is bounded from below by $x$.

Step 2: by Step 1, $\lim_na_n$ exists and equals to some $L$ satisfying $L\geq x$ and $L=\frac{L^2+1}{3}$. You can then verify that $L$ is in fact equal to $x$ above.

Comment: Any pointers on how you selected that $x$?

Comment: Thanks Andre. I was too hasty.

Comment: @ Dimitris: $x$ is one of the solutions to the equation $x=\frac{x^2+1}{3}$.

Comment: You don't need to use that specific $x$. The sequence is bounded below by $\frac13$, even $0$.