# Find the limit of recursive sequence, if it exists: $a_{n+1}=\frac{7+3a_n}{3+a_n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

My goal is to to test this recursive sequence if it's convergent and if yes, find the limit.

$$a_1=3,\:a_{n+1}=\frac{7+3a_n}{3+a_n}$$

I know how to do this with normal sequences, but this is the first time we have to use a recursive sequence.

If you calculate the first few parts you get:

n | a(n)
1 | 3
2 | 2.66667
3 | 2.64706
4 | 2.64583
5 | 2.64576
6 | 2.64575
7 | 2.64575
8 | 2.64575

So I take it the sequence is convergent against 2.64575... But how do you prove that in a calculation?

Comment: The sequence is (or rather seems to be), decreasing and bounded below. Does this ring any bells? If you happen to know it converges, take the limit on both sides of the definition of $a_{n+1}$ and solve for the limit.

Comment: This does ring bells, but if you could show me a basic template on how to do that I would really appreciate it.

FYI I'm in college and it's literally the 3rd week of the first semester and we've never done anything like this in school before.

Comment: Read the comments in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/932394/proof-of-convergence-of-a-n1-dfraca-n2-13-in-mathbbr-and-fin) question. Worked out examples can be found on MSE, I'm sure.

Answer (score 7):

Rewrite the recursion, for example

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{7+3a_n}{3+a_n}=\frac{9+3a_n}{3+a_n}-\frac{2}{3+a_n}=3-\frac{2}{3+a_n} $$
First of all, if $a_n>0$, then $a_{n+1}>3-\frac23>0$ as well. Hence by inductiuon (and as $a_1>0$), $a_n>0$ for all $n$. This shows that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded from below, as suspected.

Next observe that the bigger (positive) $x$ is, the smaller is $\frac2{3+x}$ and the bigger is $4-\frac2{3+x}$. Consequently, if $a_n>a_{n+1}$, then also $a_{n+2}=3-\frac2{3+a_{n+1}}>3-\frac2{3+a_{n}}=a_{n+1}$. Again, using the first instance of this, i.e. $a_1=3>a_2=\frac83$, we conclude by induction that $\{a_n\}$ is (strictly) decreasing.

From the above we se that the limit $a:=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ exists (why?).
Then also
$$a =\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{7+3a_n}{3+a_n}=\frac{7+3\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}}{3+\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}}=\frac{7+3a}{3+a}.$$
Can you find from this, which values of $a$ are candidates for the limit? Which of these cannot be the limit? Hence ... ?

Comment: Thanks, this helps a great deal, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

With $b_n:=a_n-\sqrt7$ and $b_n>0$, we can write

$$0<b_{n+1}=\frac{3-\sqrt7}{b_n+3+\sqrt7}b_n<\frac{3-\sqrt7}{3+\sqrt7}b_n,$$ which squeezes to zero (geometric progression) from any $b_0>0$. The convergence is linear.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that it exists, one says, $a_n \to L$, then $a_{n+1} \to L$ since $(a_{n+1})$ is a subsequence of $(a_n)$ and then, it must converge to the same limit. Now, if you apply the limit as $n \to \infty$ in the equality that definines recusively the sequence, you find:$$L = \frac{7+3L}{3+L}.$$
Solvind this equation for $L$, you find $L= \pm \sqrt{7}$. Since every term in the sequence is positive, the limit cannot be negative. Then, $L= \sqrt{7}$.